# Is it possible to combine an id/class with attributes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm just wondering ignoring the specs, is this sort of selector actually found and supported in real browsers?

I have never seen a CSS rule that combines an class and attribute selectors or id and attribute selectors. While combining Id in this way doesn't seem to make sense there are use cases like a rule that only is used when the id element is disabled.

I'm just attempting to better understand the possible real supported combinations.

Comment: Could you expand - what do you mean "combine an id/class with attributes"? Do you mean applying the same style to stuff with a certain ID or class? Or stuff with the ID and class?

Comment: I think he means selecting by ID and class, like (#idval and .classval) - never seen this myself.

Comment: @mP Can you point to an actual example where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All browsers that support IDs, classes and attribute selectors have no trouble understanding combinations of them within compound selectors. As far as I've seen, if there are any obscure bugs then these usually lie in the individual selectors, and not in the combination of the selectors (for example, IE7's not so obscure but rather infamous mishandling of attribute selectors for DOM properties).

The spec doesn't say anything specifically about combining IDs, classes and attributes, [but it does state indirectly that it's allowed and completely fair game](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax) (see *sequence of simple selectors* and *simple selector*).

Answer (score 2):

In general, since an ID will be unique, you'll never need to combine that with an attribute, however it's often helpful to precede it with stuff to see where it came from, for example:

```
.header .float-left #my_id
```

I'd say it wouldn't be unusual to combine a class with an attribute, since it's not unique, for example:

```
input.my_class[type='submit']
```

Comment: @mP. You should clarify what you mean, because on the face of it you seem certainly to be wrong.

Comment: @David542 Yes, since CSS files can be used with multiple HTML pages, your first example can be used to address the `#mi_id` only on those pages where is it in the `.float-left`, so it actually has practical purposes.